# Downscale the very large image file up to a little less large

Tags: android, image-processing

I have a very large image file (over 25MB) with dimensions about 10000x10000 px. I need to downscale this image that file was not more then 20MB. I know about

```
BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
o2.inSampleSize = <scale>;
BitmapFactory.decodeSomething(...);
```

But if `scale = 2` dimension was 5000x5000 px, that is good for me but more then android can decode and it cause `OutOfMemory`. So the question is how to downscale 10000x10000 px image file to 5000x5000 px image file? Is there a way to do it without using `Bitmap` to avoid `OutOfMemory`?

Comment: Just try [Tiny PNG](https://tinypng.com/). It will reduced size by 60-70%.. It will only reduce size(MB) not scaling image but good option.

Comment: this is completely not a mobile task, to scale such images. But as an option, you can try to load image parts, for example let's say split it to 4x4 = 16 parts, scale each of them separate, and then join them

Comment: what do you want to do with `5000x5000 px` image on your phone?

Comment: @pskink Does it matter? Send it to server.

Comment: so it doesn't matter if you use `android.graphics.BitmapRegionDecoder` and call `decodeRegion` for example 10 x 10 times

Answer (score 0):

First you need to get metadata about the image,Free required space in mobile memory if needed, Create a bitmap and draw-able object then convert the original image in A888 or other format (the image format that occupy less memory) then take a size (height ans width) of required image and draw image on Draw-able class. for more information follow this link
http://voidcanvas.com/whatsapp-like-image-compression-in-android/
it worked for me. change the image size and compression format as per requirement.